# partition problem where an element does not form a block by itself

Tags: combinatorics

How many partitions does the set [10] have in which the element 1 does not form a block by itself? On a broader sense, how many partitions does the set [n] have where element k does not form a block by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no harm in assuming that $k=n$.

Every partition of $[n]$ in which $n$ does not occupy a block by itself is obtained from a partition of $[n-1]$ by adding $n$ to one of its blocks. There are ${n-1}\brace k$ partitions of $[n-1]$ into $k$ blocks, each of which gives rise to $k$ partitions of $[n]$ of the desired type, so you want

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{{n-1}\brace k}k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left({n\brace k}-{{n-1}\brace{k-1}}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\brace k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{{n-1}\brace k}\\\\
&=\big(B(n)-1\big)-\big(B(n-1)-1\big)\\\\
&=B(n)-B(n-1)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: so the number of partitions of [10] in which the element 1 does not form a block by itself is equivalent to B(10)-B(9)?

Comment: @AlPal: Yes, it is.

Comment: can you explain why the index from k=1 to n-1 yields (B(n)-1)? I know that B(n)= summation from k=o to n of S(n,k), but cant quite explain how I know in words that the shift in the index yields (B(n)-1).

Comment: @AlPal: The $k=0$ term is $0$, and the $k=n$ term is $1$.

Comment: I have it that the (B(n-1)-1) term can be obtained in a similar fashion. Since B(n-1) is measured over the index of k=o to k=n-1 of the summation of S(n-1,k), the k=n-2 term would be equivalent to one, which is how you end up at (B(n-1)-1). This type of logic makes sense. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @AlPal: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Probably the easiest way to count these is as follows:

1. Start by choosing $k\geq1$ elements of $\{2,\ldots,10\}$ to be in the block with $1$.
2. Place any partition on the remaining $9-k$ elements.

With this, we find that the number of specialized partitions of this type is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{9}\binom{9}{k}p_{9-k},
$$
where $p_j$ is the number of partitions of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,j\}$.

Comment: Can you explain this in terms of set partitions?

Comment: @BrentSmith I'm not sure I understand -- isn't that what I did?